# How to get response over logcat while deploying a standalone signed APK via Command Line or directly thru memory card?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, logcat, android-logcat

i need to analyse the logcat response. i've created the signed apk and deployed in my device via [adb install "app_name"].apk

as there's no connection between the device and emulator window, i am unable to get the response over logcat. How would i establish the connection in between device and emulator. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can use adb install, why not adb shell logcat?

Comment: Of course there is no connection to the emulator, you are using a device instead.  You may be able to configure your ide's logcat window to monitor the device, or you can monitor it directly as Jermaine suggests.  Be aware the messages might change between devices/versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that after deploying the signed apk in the device via usb cable, the emulator logcat by default displays all the response(os level + app level) in ALL MESSAGES category without any FILTERS , usually it displays response based on project's package name. Thanks for helping ! But this is not an efficient way , it sucks !

Comment: i've got the desired result by creating a filter by APPLICATION NAME,i've used the root package name to reference the application level logs. :D